# Clarification on this <a> tag with :: symbol for webscraping

Tags: html, web-scraping

I am a beginner at using bs4 and webscraping. I am trying to scrape the stats.nba.com site. The problem i am having is that i can't seem to scrape the player's names and their points for each category. I've inspected the element and it shows up when i inspect it on the web page. But when i scrape it using bs4 it shows me for the tag i want:

`<a ng-href="/player/{{::player.PLAYER_ID}}/" title="View Stats Profile" aria-labelledby="leaders_daily_players__{{ ::category.name }}">{{::player.PLAYER_NAME}}</a>`

All the player's name is replaced by "::player.PLAYER_NAME". I've tried looking up what the :: symbol but i could not figure out why. Can someone explain what "::" does and how i would be able to scrape that info from the site?

Comment: What have you tried so far I meant, where is your failure attempt? Btw, did you forget to add the language tag or intentionally skip that?

Comment: I've tried to scrape it by its tag and class. Which gives me nothing back. I felt like it wasn't a bug or anything it was due to my lack of knowledge. what do you mean by language tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned website dynamically generates its content using Angular. Angular is run by the JavaScript engine in the browser and replaces these placeholder of *::player.PLAYER_ID* with the actual data which is loaded asynchronously.

BeautifulSoup by default just loads the HTML and does not mimic a fully functional browser. It does not execute the JavaScript part, thus the placeholders do not get replaced with the actual data.

You may try another approach to execute the JavaScript which is documented at https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/

Another approach might be to utilize existing API projects: https://github.com/seemethere/nba_py/wiki/stats.nba.com-Endpoint-Documentation